# Fiber holder with 'vacuum' holes.

Tags: experimental-physics, fiber-optics

I'm a student in my third semester and am currently working with workgroup in our physics department. Last week our lab got access to liquid nitrogen and we are fiddling around with fibers in particular. For that purpose I got the task to build a fiber holder. I was told that I could use Autodesk which is available on the PCs there. The thing is I never worked with Autodesk before or any sort of software of the like. Neither did I ever build a fiber holder. So first I tried making some sketches on my notebook. Here's what I got: [image]

The 8 'circles' on the left one are for screws and the 3 smaller circles in the notch on the right are for vacuuming the fiber tight to the fiber holder. And for that I guess there would have to be a tube of some sort in the fiber holder so the vacuuming can work.

Now, my question is: Is that good enough for a fiber holder? And would I be able to create the same thing on Autodesk that easily without having any experience with it?

Comment: You might want to look at available fiber holders from places like Newport and Thorlabs. Most use mechanical pressure rather than vacuum to hold the fiber. One potential issue I'd anticipate with a vacuum-based holder is the difficulty of applying vacuum without producing vibration.

Comment: You might want to add information about the need for this holder. Why are you holding this fiber in conjunction with liquid $N_2$? How big are the fibers? How firmly do they need to be held against applied forces? And, [what about Naomi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Love_of_Chair)?